# Jquery code only working when display not none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cart icon. When I hover on the cart icon display of one div changes from `display:none` to `display:block` means that div only appears when I hover on cart icon. This div contains one button **View Cart** on clicking which I need to alert something.

This is my code which I typed in console. But it only works when I first hover the icon (hovering icon changes `display:none` of a div to `display:block`) and then write on console. If I write this code in console before hovering it will not work.

```
$('#qa_cartletCartButton').click( function(){alert('yes');} );
```

ID of `div`: `cartletDrop`

ID of `button`: `qa_cartletCartButton`

These codes are also not working.

```js
if ($('#cartletDrop').is(':hidden')) {
  $("#qa_cartletCartButton").click(function() {
    alert('yes')
  });
}
```

```js
if ($('#cartletDrop').is(':visible')) {
  $("#qa_cartletCartButton").click(function() {
    alert('yes')
  });
}
```

This is the site HTML code which I am **scraping**.

```
<div class="shopping_cart">
  <header class="header">
    <a href="/chemicals/shop/cart?nocache=1596440273788" class="shopping_cart_icon" id="shopping_cart_icon_cartlet">
      <span><img src="/content/dam/fishersci/en_US/images/icon-cart-l-xl-empty.svg"></span>
      <span class="shopping_cart_quantity">3</span>
    </a>
  </header>
  <section style="display: none;" id="cartletDrop" data-refresh="0">
    <div class="cartlet-display">
      <p class="bold cartletMaxMsg" id="qa_cartletMaxMsg">Recently Added to Your Cart</p>
      <ul id="cartletItems">
      </ul>
      <p class="cartletSubtotal"><span class="float_left" id="qa_cartletSubtotalLabel">Subtotal:</span> <span class="float_right" id="qa_cartletSubtotal">41,486.00</span></p>
      <p><a class="float_right cartButton btn primary" href="/chemicals/shop/cart?nocache=1596440278170" id="qa_cartletCartButton">view cart</a></p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This line in html is empty before i hover.

```
 <section style="display: none;" id="cartletDrop" data-refresh="0">
</section>
```

Once i hover in cart icon it's now like this.Only display property changes.

```
  <section style="display: none;" id="cartletDrop" data-refresh="0">
    <div class="cartlet-display">
      <p class="bold cartletMaxMsg" id="qa_cartletMaxMsg">Recently Added to Your Cart</p>
      <ul id="cartletItems">
      </ul>
      <p class="cartletSubtotal"><span class="float_left" id="qa_cartletSubtotalLabel">Subtotal:</span> <span class="float_right" id="qa_cartletSubtotal">41,486.00</span></p>
      <p><a class="float_right cartButton btn primary" href="/chemicals/shop/cart?nocache=1596440278170" id="qa_cartletCartButton">view cart</a></p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

seems html inside section tag is not present before first hover.

Comment: You are missing the # in the first example code, before qa_cartletCartButton. You also may need to add ; after the alert, depending on weather you are using strict js. Other than that, we need your markup code to be able to help you, as weltscmerz pointed out. In the meantime: are you sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: Try [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach once i.e.  `$(document).on('click', "#qa_cartletCartButton", function(){   
    alert("clicked me");  
});`

Comment: @Satpal added few lines at last of question please check sir.